# How do I get the user's email when using Microsoft Account Authentication in an MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I have modified **startup.Auth.cs** so that I could add scopes. Here is what I have:

```
MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions mo = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "My Client ID",
    ClientSecret = "My Client Secret",
};
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(mo);
```

This allows me to authenticate the user.

I have tried adding the scopes *wl.signin, wl.emails* and *wl.contacts_emails*. However, they cause the Microsoft login page to report the following error: **AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope wl.signin, wl.emails, wl.contacts_emails is not valid.** The scope combination of *openid* and *email* seems to work. However, the scope *openid* is overkill for what I am trying to do. That is, I think it is too much to ask from the user. The scope *email* all by it self doesn't work.

This is particularly weird because the template that Visual Studio sets up assumes that the external authentication provider will supply an email address.

How do I get only the user's email?

For context, I am using the following documents: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#openid-permissions which gives the impression that I want *email* and *profile* included in the scope. However, it goes on to state that they are included by default.

I am trying to implement external Authentication in my MVC project using the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins.

Comment: This is a ASP.Net Web Application(.Net Framework). I am going to try the whole thing with an ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core). the interface is slightly different i.e it uses MicrosoftAccountOptions instead of MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to use **ASP.Net *Core* Web Application (.Net Framework)** to get the email. The code is similar but *note*: **MicrosoftAccountOptions** instead of **MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions**.

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions()
{
    ClientId = "My Client ID",
    ClientSecret = "My Client Secret"
});
```

Intrestingly enough this does not notify the user that you are getting their email address. I have Google, Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft & LinkedIn working. Now on to AccountKit for email and SMS logins.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add scopes:

```
MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions mo = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "My Client ID",
    ClientSecret = "My Client Secret",
};
mo.Scope.Add("openid");
mo.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(mo);
```

Comment: In the question you will note that I tried that. It does ask permission to access the users email. However, the email is not returned in loginInfo or ClaimsPrincipal.Current. How do I retrieve the email?

Comment: Facebook and Google return the email in loginInfo. Where does Microsoft put it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the email address of a user.

```
 ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value.Split('#')[ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value.Split('#').Length - 1];
```

Comment: I tried to use this in ExternalLoginCallback. However, it does not return anything. I think the underlying issue is that I do not know how to get the email in the scope of the original request. As a result loginInfo does not contain the information and I am not able to find it anywhere in the ClaimsPrincipal.Current. I was able to add email to the scope of Facebook. Google had email in by default. In the case of Twitter i had to call their credentials verification API to get it (a solution I don't like but, I don't know any other way of getting the email from Twitter).